# Is there a JQuery UI layout interface for Typescript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, jquery-layout

Is there a JQuery UI layout interface for Typescript? Has one been written? I cannot find one and would like to avoid writing one myself.

Answer (score 1):

[Definitely Typed](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) is the largest source for type definitions.

And they do indeed have a [definition for jQuery UI](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jqueryui).

And they will [soon have a definition for jQuery UI Layout](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/746/files) - although it is a basic version right now as I'm not familiar with the implementation.

Comment: Steve, I could be wrong, but I believe the OP's referring to the jQuery UI Layout plugin, which I can't find a definition file for on the Definitely Typed repository

Comment: Thanks for the definition for jQuery UI, but this isn't the layout plugin as Anzeo has said.

Comment: I have created a first draft of the definition, which will fix any errors you are getting. I haven't drilled in all the way to give you perfect typings, but it is a start: https://github.com/Steve-Fenton/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery.ui.layout/jquery.ui.layout.d.ts